# How redirect from url to the part of this url .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can you, please, tell how to make a redirect with apache .htaccess:

**from** `http://www.domain1.com/products/?http://www.domain2.com/sdssds?%dfdf`

**to**  `http://www.domain2.com/sdssds?%dfdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+products/\?([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=302,NE]
```